# How to create a submenu for a popup menu?

Tags: c, winapi

When I want to create a popup menu, I would use the `CreatePopupMenu()` function.

But what if one of the popup menu items needs to have a submenu, should I also use `CreatePopupMenu()` to create the submenu, or should I use `CreateMenu()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CreateMenu` is for Window's horizontal menu bar. You can use `CreatePopupMenu` to make popup menu, as well as submenu for the popup:

```
HMENU submenu = CreatePopupMenu();
AppendMenu(submenu, MF_STRING, 1001, L"submenu 1001");

HMENU mainmenu = CreatePopupMenu();
AppendMenu(mainmenu, MF_STRING, 100, L"main 100");
AppendMenu(mainmenu, MF_SEPARATOR, 0, NULL);
AppendMenu(mainmenu, MF_STRING, 101, L"main 101");

AppendMenu(mainmenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT)submenu, L"&submenu");

POINT p;
GetCursorPos(&p);
TrackPopupMenu(mainmenu, TPM_LEFTBUTTON, p.x, p.y, 0, hdlg, 0);
```

Comment: So I should indeed use `CreatePopupMenu()` for the submenu also. Thanks.

Comment: paul, yes sorry I didn't read the question right. I updated the answer, it's what you said.